# Constructing tests using pivots

Tags: statistics

I don't understand how to construct tests using pivots in general. I know the following:

We want to test $H_{\gamma_0}:\gamma=\gamma_0.$ A pivot is a function $Z(X,\gamma)$ depending on the data $X$ and on the unknown parameter $\gamma$ such that $\forall\theta$ the distribution $\mathbb{P}_\theta(Z(X,g(\theta))\leq \cdot)=:G$ does not depend on $\theta$. If we have a pivot $Z(X,\gamma)$ with distribution $G$, we can compute its quantile functions
\begin{align*}
q_L:=q_{\sup}^G(\alpha/2):=\sup\{ x:G(x)\leq \alpha/2 \},\\
q_R:=q_{\inf}^G(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})=\inf\{ x:G(x)\geq 1-\frac{\alpha}{2} \}, 
\end{align*}
and the test
\begin{align*}
\Phi(X,\gamma_0) =  \begin{cases} 1\quad \text{if}\quad Z(X,\gamma)\not\in[q_L,q_R]  \\ 
0 \quad else  \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Then the test has level $\alpha$ for testing $H_{\gamma_0}$.

Maybe someone can illustrate it at the following example. Let $X,Y$ be independent RV's with $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\nu,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\eta,1)$. Let the parameter of interest be $\theta=\nu/\eta$. Now I want to show that
\begin{align*}
\Phi(X,Y,\theta_0) =  \begin{cases} 0\quad \text{if}\quad |X-\theta_0Y|\leq c_\alpha\sqrt{1+\theta_0^2}  \\ 
1 \quad else  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

is a test of $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ at level $\alpha$ and I want to calculate $c_\alpha$. How could I approach such a problem?

Comment: You typically use pivots here to construct confidence intervals of your parameter. A test can then be found from this confidence interval. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like to do but I don't know how to start..